# TruClient IE Browser is not rendering the pages correctly

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

When recording with True Client protocol, login page is getting recorded and after that browser is not displaying anything in home page.

```
Script_View_Action()
{
    truclient_step("1", "Navigate to 'http://server:port/xyz'", "snapshot=Action_1.inf");
    truclient_step("2", "Activate tab #1", "snapshot=Action_2.inf");
    truclient_step("3", "form (1)", "snapshot=Action_3.inf");
    {
        truclient_step("3.1", "Type user1 in User ID textbox", "snapshot=Action_3.1.inf");
        truclient_step("3.2", "Type ********* in Password passwordbox", "snapshot=Action_3.2.inf");
        truclient_step("3.3", "Press Enter key on Password passwordbox", "snapshot=Action_3.3.inf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you state the problem more clearly? What are you asking?

Comment: I am scripting an application in loadrunner using TrueClient protocol. Loadrunner version is 12.02.

Comment: It successfully launches application in TrueClient IE browser, able to enter values for user ID and password and when clicked Enter, nothing is getting displayed in home page. It works perfectly when I do the same from IE browser outside loadrunner in the same machine.

Comment: When you say "nothing is getting displayed in home page" do you mean that nothing is getting recorded in the TruClient tab?

If that is the case then it might be that you have other IE windows open on the machine. (The hooks from Loadrunner might get caught in one of the other instances). This happened to me recently.